# Where to purchase sushi-grade ahi tuna in Arizona? (or purchase online overnight shipping)

Tags: sushi

I was looking around and I couldn't find any good options for buying ahi tuna for sushi/sashimi in Arizona and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

I've also tried online at Honolulu Fishing Market, Seattle Fish Company and Catalina. No luck here.

BONUS: If I go to Costco or the like is the fish here also acceptable for sushi/sashimi/nigiri?

Comment: I've not heard of 'ahi grade tuna' - can you clarify please?  I thought ahi was another name for yellowfin/yellowtail (a species of tuna).

Comment: @NatBowman typo, fixed.

Comment: You can't use fresh fish for sushi. The process for making fish safe for raw consumption is to freeze it.

Comment: @Catija correct. However depending on where you buy it from they may freeze, thaw, freeze, etc. So I'm just being safe.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean sushi grade ahi tuna, you can’t buy it or consume it fresh, because of parasites in the flesh. All sushi grade fish is held frozen at 0°F for at least forty eight hours to kill the parasites.

If you don’t have a local source for sushi grade tuna, you can find a variety of reliable shippers on-line, although they can be a bit pricey.

Comment: Correct it cannot be "fresh," in the typical sense. Rather fresh in the sense that the distributor is handling it correctly so that it may stay usable for sushi.